# Easier way to set connection strings for solr cores?

Tags: solr, configuration

We had a company do our new search and they used solr to do it with. When they make a change to schema though, they send us a zip with new cores and I have to go into every folder and update the connection settings in all the data-config.xml files again which is a real pain cause there are like 20 of them.

Is there a better way I could do this because they all have the exact same connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, make them get the relevant data as request parameters, as explained [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Accessing_request_parameters)

So the datasource would look something like:

```
    <dataSource driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${dataimporter.request.DBHOST}:1521:${dataimporter.request.DBNAME}" user="${dataimporter.request.DBUSERNAME}" password="${dataimporter.request.DBPASSWORD}"/>
```

in case of an Oracle db for instance, then you pass the right parameters when calling dih:

```
http://.../dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true&commit=true&DBHOST=1.1.1.1&DBNAME=mydb&DBUSERNAME=user&DBPASSWORD=passw
```